# how to make button start new activity containing android googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps

i have created class which display google map but i want to make class start first
when i press this class button go to googlemap class
the app is crashing when i press this button
this is my code of the new class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class homepage extends MainActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout1);


}
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity"));
    }
    public void onClick1(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.gmapsapp.homepage2"));
    }

}
```

this for mainactivity which contain map

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private static final int GPS_ERRORDIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final double NASRCITY_LAT = 30.066108,
    NASRCITY_LNG =31.336184;
    private static final float DEFAULTZOOM = 13;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (servicesOK()) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

            if (initMap()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Ready to map!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                gotoLocation(NASRCITY_LAT, NASRCITY_LNG, DEFAULTZOOM);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    }
```

the logcat is

```
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 2579
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     ... 11 more
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity }
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     at com.example.gmapsapp.homepage.onClick(homepage.java:15)
03-28 12:40:22.260: E/AndroidRuntime(2579):     ... 14 more
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 2638
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     ... 11 more
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.gmapsapp.homepage2 }
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     at com.example.gmapsapp.homepage.onClick1(homepage.java:18)
03-28 12:40:36.530: E/AndroidRuntime(2638):     ... 14 more
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 2714
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     ... 11 more
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity }
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     at com.example.gmapsapp.homepage.onClick(homepage.java:15)
03-28 12:45:34.175: E/AndroidRuntime(2714):     ... 14 more
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 2800
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     ... 11 more
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.gmapsapp.FragmentActivity }
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     at com.example.gmapsapp.homepage.onClick(homepage.java:15)
03-28 12:46:06.655: E/AndroidRuntime(2800):     ... 14 more
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 2883
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     ... 11 more
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity }
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     at com.example.gmapsapp.homepage.onClick(homepage.java:15)
03-28 13:12:43.609: E/AndroidRuntime(2883):     ... 14 more
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): Process: com.example.gmapsapp, PID: 2947
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     ... 11 more
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity }
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     at com.example.gmapsapp.homepage.onClick(homepage.java:15)
03-28 13:24:29.900: E/AndroidRuntime(2947):     ... 14 more
```

the mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gmapsapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

          <activity
            android:name=".homepage"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAFjx4uMoTXzaYrSMyYeOnnE1pUeRVgxEA"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

and sorry for bad english

Comment: Add the crash logs as well

Comment: where have you initialised button code?

Comment: i have edited the project and add the logcat

Comment: The log says that you dont have such an activity.Have you declared the activity in manifest?

Comment: lal : the button works well but when i press it it should be go to the main activity but the app crash

Comment: yes i will edit the post and add the mainfest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't added any crash logs
but an error may be here:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent("com.example.gmapsapp.MainActivity"));
}
```

I would change it to this:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Or you forgot do declare an activity with Google Maps in Manifest